# How to get PhpStorm to auto import namespaced functions?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I know PhpStorm can auto import classes but I cannot figure out how to get it to auto import namespaced functions.

Here is my namespaced function:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Utility\Safe;

function base64_decode($string)
{
    $result = \base64_decode($string, true);
    if (!\is_string($result)) {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

When I start typing base64_decode() PhpStorm is able to suggest the namespaced version, but when I click it, it inputs the fully qualified namespace.

```php
// I get this:
\App\Utility\Safe\base64_decode();

//I want this:
use function App\Utility\Safe\base64_decode;

base64_decode();
```

Comment: Please check the following ticket, looks like, it covers your scenario:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57246